# get width/height of two selected points in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have a canvas which display a picture that The user has uploaded.What I want to do is to ask the client to give me the width and height between two points that he/she has selected on canvas in cm .For example,The client click on top left on canvas and then select top right .after that he/she should enter the width between those two selected points.
How should I do that?

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just get the coordinates of your two points.

Let us assume the first point is called `A` and the second point is called `B`. So their coordinates would be:

```
A = (xa, ya)
B = (xb, xb)
```

So the horizontal distance between `A` and `B` would be, `|xa-xb|`<sup>1</sup>. And the vertical distance between them would be `|ya-yb|`<sup>1</sup>.

If we draw a rectangle using `A` and `B` as diagonally opposite points of it, that rectangle's width would be `|xa-xb|`, and it's height would be `|ya-yb|`.

---

1. `||` represents "Absolute Value". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value.

Comment: actually ,for example,the picture is from a room that the user has uploaded .I want to have the width between that two points in cm.So the user has to enter that for me.So I need the user to enter that after selecting two points.

Comment: Then I guess you will have to catch the click event on the `canvas` and then see if it's a second click. If it is, present the user with a text box to enter the width.

Then you can save all the details in a Javascript object like following:

    {
        x: Your x coordinate.,
        y: Your y coordinate.,
        w: The width the user typed.
    }

Comment: How should I add a shadow or something after the first click of the user on the picture ,So he knows that HE/she has to choose another point like re sizing?Could you help me with that please